# I need a quick help on the below mdx query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, mdx, mdxstudio, mdxclient

I want to filter the data on the measure and dimension at a time

```
case 
when [measure].[frequency] >3 and [poa].[segment].&A then 'red'
when [measure].[frequency] <3 and [poa].[segment].&A then 'yellow'
when [measure].[frequency] =3 and [poa].[segment].&A then 'Green'
else 'NA' end
```

these the script i have written in the calculated member .. but it is not running successfully.Kindly help us

Comment: Why is it not working? Do you get an error or incorrect results? Provide a screenshot of the wrong results and your desired results.

Comment: it showing the error like #valueerr

Comment: This is not a help desk where you can request us to answer ASAP.

Comment: @AdiT please install OLAP PivotTable Extensions then right click on the #VALUE! cell and get a better error message. http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%20Error%20Message&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to put a currentMember comparison in the case?

I guess this would work ok?

```
case 
when [measure].[frequency] >3 then 'red'
when [measure].[frequency] <3 then 'yellow'
when [measure].[frequency] =3 then 'Green'
else 'NA' 
end
```

Although do you have to use 'NA'? Can you not use `null` in this situation?

```
case 
when [measure].[frequency] >3 then 'red'
when [measure].[frequency] <3 then 'yellow'
when [measure].[frequency] =3 then 'Green'
else NULL 
end
```

The other section of you calc looks like it needs to compare `[poa].[segment].&A` against something using the `IS` operator like this:

```
([poa].CURRENTMEMBER IS [poa].[segment].&A)
```

So adding this into the `case` statement:

```
CASE
WHEN [measure].[frequency] >3 
        AND ([poa].CURRENTMEMBER IS [poa].[segment].&A) THEN 'red'
WHEN [measure].[frequency] <3 
        AND ([poa].CURRENTMEMBER IS [poa].[segment].&A) THEN 'yellow'
WHEN [measure].[frequency] =3 
        AND ([poa].CURRENTMEMBER IS [poa].[segment].&A) THEN 'Green'
ELSE NULL 
END
```